# How many permutations avoid previous adjacencies?

Tags: combinatorics

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210161/probability-and-permutation-and-combination) was asked by another user. It was closed and deleted, taking with it an answer of mine that I think people might find useful. So I'm reposting the question, and my answer (lightly edited).

Seven friends went to see a movie. At the time of interval they went away. In how many ways when they come back can they sit that no two previously adjacent people will sit together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, and much more, is available [here](http://oeis.org/A002464) at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

With $n$ friends (instead of 7), the number of ways, $a(n)$, satisfies the recurrence, 
$$a(n) = (n+1)a(n-1)-(n-2)a(n-2)-(n-5)a(n-3)+(n-3)a(n-4)$$ with $a(0)=a(1)=1$, $a(2)=a(3)=0$. The closest thing to a closed-form formula is $$a(n)=n!+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\sum_{t=1}^k{k-1\choose t-1}{n-k\choose t}2^t(n-k)!$$  There's an asymptotic expansion $${a(n)\over n!}\sim e^{-2}\bigl(1-2n^{-2}-(10/3)n^{-3}-6n^{-4}-(154/15)n^{-5}\bigr)$$

Of course, the question as posed doesn't ask for a general formula or asymptotics, just for $a(7)$, which is 646.

Comment: Could you explain in more details the recursive relationship for $a(n)$?

Comment: @Kim, sorry, I was just quoting the OEIS page, not presenting my own work. There may be some reference on that page.

Comment: this can be solved easier then the approach u used. try the case for 5 friends,  then u can generalize for odd n

Comment: @Randin, show me.

Answer (score 0):

when they return 
the friend in first seat can only have 8 of the other friends sitting next to him .once one of those sits in seat two , that friend now have 6 to chose from ect so probability is (8/9)(7/8)(6/7)(5/6)(4/5)(3/4)(2/3)(1/2)

Comment: The question asks for 'how many ways' this can happen, not the probability.

Comment: yep  I realized thgat after I posted it . it's still neat but should I delete it?

Comment: Just edit your question.

Comment: or delete my answer?

Comment: tobymak 39 can this be solved with combinatorics?

Comment: Does your method give you the same answer as the one I cite in my post? If not, your approach is probably wrong.

Comment: Anything to say, Randin?

Comment: hi Gerry,  I guess there is no other way . you did use combinatorics to solve it right? binomial ? I wonder wgat was wrong with my solution which I thought was elegant

Comment: I didn't solve it, I just pointed to a website which has links to places where it is solved. Follow the links, if you want to see how it was solved.

Comment: Gerry , how does this problem have to do with kings,on a chessboard? that was the oeis